# Can we merge [ia64] and [itanium] tags?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

They're the same. But there's no wiki for [ia64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ia64)

[ia64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ia64)

> It is a 64-bit register-rich explicitly parallel CPU architecture from Intel.

[itanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itanium)

> > Itanium is a family of 64-bit Intel microprocessors based on explicit instruction-level parallelism, in which the compiler decides which instructions to execute in parallel. This contrasts with superscalar architectures, which depend on the processor to manage instruction dependencies at runtime
>
> Itanium (/aɪˈteɪniəm/) is a family of 64-bit Intel microprocessors that implement the Intel Itanium architecture (formerly called IA-64). Intel markets the processors for enterprise servers and high-performance computing systems. The architecture originated at Hewlett-Packard (HP), and was later jointly developed by HP and Intel.
>
> The Itanium architecture is based on explicit instruction-level parallelism, in which the compiler decides which instructions to execute in parallel. This contrasts with other superscalar architectures, which depend on the processor to manage instruction dependencies at runtime. Itanium cores up to and including Tukwila execute up to six instructions per clock cycle.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium

Answer (score 14):

**Yes, they should be merged and synonymized**, as IA-64 is the same thing as Itanium.

Unfortunately, since the tag synonym system is horribly broken and continues to escape the developers' attention, this is not something that the community can do themselves. It will require <strike>God's</strike> a moderator's hand.

Personally, I would vote for making [itanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itanium) the "master" tag, since it is less ambiguous than [ia64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ia64), which people occasionally mistake for x86-64 (aka AMD64, the 64-bit extensions to the IA-32 ISA).

Comment: For what it's worth, [the Intel page for one of their Itanium processors](http://ark.intel.com/products/71699/Intel-Itanium-Processor-9560-32M-Cache-2_53-GHz) doesn't say "IA-64" anywhere. It seems that they've backed away from that term.